# No CSRF input field in html form of django rest framework in PUT method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

PUT, DELETE method is generating this error when submitted from the api webpage

```
{
    "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}
```

But POST method is working fine in the same API modal created using **viewsets.ModelViewSet**

So I inspect the form and found that the post method has CSRF input field but PUT html form doesn't have the CSRF so the error is showing how can I fix this issue.

Package used:

> Django==2.2.5 
> djangorestframework==3.7.7 
> django-rest-auth==0.9.5 
> django-filter==2.2.0

settings.py file

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ],
}
```

[image: PUT HTML FORM in DRF Template]
Why DRF template adds the CSRF field in POST HTML form but doesn't add that field in PUT HTML form. I am ready to provide any additional info if required is there anything I had missed in the setup.

URL

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'comment', CommentViewSet, base_name='comment')
```

ViewSet

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ContentTypePermission]

    def get_queryset(self):
        model_type = self.request.GET.get("type")
        pk = self.request.GET.get("id")
        content_type_model = ContentType.objects.get(model=model_type.lower())
        model_class = content_type_model.model_class()
        model_obj = model_class.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
        return Comment.objects.filter_parents_by_object(model_obj)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        model_type = self.request.GET.get("type")
        content_type_model = ContentType.objects.get(model=model_type.lower())
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user,
                 content_type=content_type_model,
                 object_id=self.request.GET.get("id"))
```

Comment: Have you tried to call this endpoint from Postman or any other API clients?

Comment: Can you share urls.py and your view along with request url and headers?

Comment: @Sumithran yes it works fine with the Postman
I call the PUT request by passing the authorization token in the header and then, the same 4 fields as shown in the image HTML form in body

Comment: @KutayAslan Everything works fine, the only problem I see is no CSRF input field in that HTML form generated by the DRF. This causes an error to test the PUT and DELETE method from the webpage. All methods works when submitted from outside using token-based authorization, but only GET, POST, RETRIEVE works from that webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support, I found the answer it was some problem with old
djangorestframework library **I upgraded the library from 3.7.7 to 3.12.2**

> djangorestframework==3.12.2

I exactly don't understand why the old library doesn't support that CSRF case. But with the upgrade it works fine without changing any code one small change I made is previously I have written basename in the URL now with the upgrade it shows an error there and I removed that part.

Old code

```
router.register(r'comment', CommentViewSet, base_name='comment')
```

New code

```
router.register(r'comment', CommentViewSet)
```

**New Update:**
Sorry, I can't regenerate this error again even when I switch back to the previous library so my thought in this is that the error of CSRF was due to the chrome cookie. As you can see in the below comment that the old library uses the cookie name parameter but the new one used another way. In my case maybe the cookie was not working and the error was showing and after the upgrade it works, now switching back also works. Anyway, the latest version of DRF seems more compatible so upgrading to is good.

Comment: Actually, the CSRF field was not in the new upgrade also instead the CSRF token was sent from JS script in PUT method.

New Upgrade:
`<script>
window.drf = {
          csrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFTOKEN",
          csrfToken: "FWM7ZipMTy5PRBVDVX7xQqqEFCQlXvRgEhHLS8f3IqUMYqaWt5sTTWIg8OMcxWjw"
        };
</script>`

In Previous library:
`<script>
window.drf = {
          csrfHeaderName: "X-CSRFTOKEN",
          csrfCookieName: "csrftoken"
        };
</script>
`
Maybe this was the issue of not getting token.